# How do I combine LINQ expressions into one?

Tags: linq

I've got a form with multiple fields on it (company name, postcode, etc.) which allows a user to search for companies in a database. If the user enters values in more than one field then I need to search on all of those fields. I am using LINQ to query the database.

So far I have managed to write a function which will look at their input and turn it into a List of expressions. I now want to turn that List into a single expression which I can then execute via the LINQ provider.

My initial attempt was as follows

```
private Expression<Func<Company, bool>> Combine(IList<Expression<Func<Company, bool>>> expressions)
    {
        if (expressions.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (expressions.Count == 1)
        {
            return expressions[0];
        }
        Expression<Func<Company, bool>> combined = expressions[0];
        expressions.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(expr => combined = Expression.And(combined, expr));
        return combined;
    }
```

However this fails with an exception message along the lines of "The binary operator And is not defined for...". Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do to combine these expressions?

EDIT: Corrected the line where I had forgotten to assign the result of and'ing the expressions together to a variable. Thanks for pointing that out folks.

Comment: If you need just logical 'And' it's better to use AndAlso to avoid unncecessary evaluations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: Jason's answer is now fuller than mine was in terms of the expression tree stuff, so I've removed that bit. However, I wanted to leave this:

I assume you're using these for a `Where` clause... why not just call Where with each expression in turn? That should have the same effect:

```
var query = ...;
foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    query = query.Where(condition);
}
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: `combined` will be typed as an `Expression`; you need to do some work to return it as an `Expression<Func<Company, bool>>`.

Comment: I agree your first code is easier to understand, so I will make this the correct answer. However I am actually going to use the second snippet as this is exactly what I need - I was making things far too complex, thanks Jon.

Comment: Ironically I was editing while both of these comments were written - but as it was this second snippet that was used, I think I'll leave it as it is :)

Answer (score 30):

You can use [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) combined with [`Expression.AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520.aspx). Here's a generic version:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAll<T>(
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> expressions) {

    if(expressions == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("expressions");
    }
    if(expressions.Count() == 0) {
        return t => true;
    }
    Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>)
                            .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                            .MakeGenericType(new[] {
                                typeof(T),
                                typeof(bool) 
                            }
                        );
    var combined = expressions
                       .Cast<Expression>()
                       .Aggregate((e1, e2) => Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2));
    return (Expression<Func<T,bool>>)Expression.Lambda(delegateType, combined);
}
```

Your current code is never assigning to `combined`:

```
expr => Expression.And(combined, expr);
```

returns a new `Expression` that is the result of bitwise anding `combined` and `expr` but it does not mutate `combined`.

Comment: +1 for a technically great answer, thanks. I've accepted Jon's as it appears simpler and also his use of Where is actually what I should be doing.

Comment: @gilles27: Yeah, if you're only using it for the predicate in a `Where` clause, then Jon's answer is the way to go. If you ever need a more general version, my version will help you. :-)

Comment: I tried this but got the runtime error "System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration"

Answer (score 2):

Here we have a general question about combining Linq expressions. I have a general solution for this problem. I will provide an answer regarding the specific problem posted, although it's definitely not the way to go in such cases. But when simple solutions fail in your case, you may try to use this approach.

First you need a library consisting of 2 simple functions. They use `System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor` to dynamically modify expressions. The key feature is unifying parameters inside the expression, so that 2 parameters with the same name were made identical (`UnifyParametersByName`). The remaining part is replacing a named parameter with given expression (`ReplacePar`). The library is available with MIT license on github: LinqExprHelper, but you may quickly write something on your own.

The library allows for quite simple syntax for combining complex expressions. You can mix inline lambda expressions, which are nice to read, together with dynamic expression creation and composition, which is very capable.

```
    private static Expression<Func<Company, bool>> Combine(IList<Expression<Func<Company, bool>>> expressions)
    {
        if (expressions.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Prepare a master expression, used to combine other
        // expressions. It needs more input parameters, they will
        // be reduced later.
        // There is a small inconvenience here: you have to use
        // the same name "c" for the parameter in your input
        // expressions. But it may be all done in a smarter way.
        Expression <Func<Company, bool, bool, bool>> combiningExpr =
            (c, expr1, expr2) => expr1 && expr2;

        LambdaExpression combined = expressions[0];
        foreach (var expr in expressions.Skip(1))
        {
            // ReplacePar comes from the library, it's an extension
            // requiring `using LinqExprHelper`.
            combined = combiningExpr
                .ReplacePar("expr1", combined.Body)
                .ReplacePar("expr2", expr.Body);
        }
        return (Expression<Func<Company, bool>>)combined;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two expression e1 and e2, you can try this:

```
var combineBody = Expression.AndAlso(e1.Body, Expression.Invoke(e2, e1.Parameters[0]));
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TestClass, bool>>(combineBody, e1.Parameters).Compile();
```